# Lua - I have created a frame in Lua but am stumped on how to insert text into it?

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

```
local MyAddon = CreateFrame("frame","MyAddonFrame")
MyAddon:SetBackdrop({
      bgFile="Interface\\DialogFrame\\UI-DialogBox-Background", 
      edgeFile="Interface\\DialogFrame\\UI-DialogBox-Border", 
      tile=1, tileSize=32, edgeSize=32, 
      insets={left=11, right=12, top=12, bottom=11}
})
MyAddon:SetWidth(220)
MyAddon:SetHeight(400)
MyAddon:SetPoint("CENTER",UIParent)
MyAddon:EnableMouse(true)
MyAddon:SetMovable(true)
MyAddon:RegisterForDrag("LeftButton")
MyAddon:SetScript("OnDragStart", function(self) self:StartMoving() end)
MyAddon:SetScript("OnDragStart", function(self) self:StartMoving() end)
MyAddon:SetScript("OnDragStop", function(self) self:StopMovingOrSizing() end)
MyAddon:SetFrameStrata("FULLSCREEN_DIALOG")



MyAddon:RegisterEvent("PLAYER_ENTERING_WORLD");
local function eventHandler(self, event, ...)
 print("Hello World! Hello " .. event);
end
MyAddon:SetScript("OnEvent", eventHandler);
```

I have coded a frame to be created in Lua, and just want to simply put in "Hello World" so that the text is a part of the frame.

Any advice?

Comment: Please tell us what framework or game engine you are using -- this is not just Lua. Where does CreateFrame come from?

Comment: A quick google search for "UI-DialogBox-Background" makes me think this is a World of Warcraft question.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want the [`CreateFontString` function](https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/API_Frame_CreateFontString):

```
local helloFS = MyAddon:CreateFontString(nil, "OVERLAY", "GameFontNormal")
helloFS:SetPoint("CENTER")
helloFS:SetText("Hello World!")
```

Comment: Doc link for this: https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/UIOBJECT_FontString ; doc link for `Frame` https://wowpedia.fandom.com/wiki/UIOBJECT_Frame